# Win11 - DNS lookup is slow when connected to AWS VPN

Tags: domain-name-system, vpn, windows-11

I need to connect to works VPN using [AWS VPN Client v3.5.0](https://aws.amazon.com/vpn/client-vpn-download/), but when I do this I get severe lag on DNS lookups for public domains

[image: slow dns lookup of 8s]

This does not happen when the VPN is disconnected and it is not an issue for any other team members, however as far as I know they are not on Win11.

I have:

- Checked that there is no other VPN client installed
- Disabled IPV6 on both my wi-fi connection and the vpn connection
- Installed and ran wireshark which apparently fixed a similar issue with win10 for some people
- Ran `Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceAlias Wi-Fi -InterfaceMetric 4` [advised by someone with a similar issue](https://gitlab.com/openconnect/openconnect/-/issues/20)
- Reinstalled the VPN client
- Updated windows to latest

Windows details:

```
Edition Windows 11 Pro
Version 22H2
Installed on    ‎17/‎05/‎2023
OS build    22621.1778
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22642.1000.0
```

Comment: amazon have troubleshooting tutorial https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/client-vpn-fix-packet-loss-latency and just by googling look like their client is a mess and have many problems, If you have control over dns in their client, or maybe it have some TAP interface you can also try to replace first DNS to something like cloudflare 1.1.1.1